# labview daq-mx dynamic buffer size

Tags: dynamic, labview, daq-mx

I want to record large amount of data in continuous mode, using a PCI 6110 and DAQ-assistant VI. At this point, I'm thinking how to dynamically change the buffer size, but I'm not sure if this is possible or if it will affect how data will differ between different sizes of the buffer.

[labVIEW diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udqT2.jpg)

At a high rate and high number of samples, after I start the VI, sometimes it returns a buffer overflow error, other times a not enough memory error. I'd want to know if dynamically changing the buffer size is achievable and how this could be done, or at least to determine a method to find a buffer size that is stable and won't overflow or throw errors during data acquisition.

Answer (score 1):

For high-performance acquisitions, I recommend using the DAQmx API to configure the device to log directly to disk. NI calls this "Log to TDMS File" and more information is available here: [TDMS Direct Integration in NI-DAQmx Logging](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9574/en/).

[image: VI block diagram for logging data to TDMS]

With this approach, you can *"stream data to disk reaching speeds up to 1.2 GB/s."*